# Why is my GNUMakefile ignored during micropython build?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, micropython, esp-idf

I'm trying to compile micropython for the ESP32.

( git@github.com:micropython/micropython.git and git@github.com:espressif/esp-idf.git)

in micropython/ports/esp32/GNUMakefile I have variables defined like so:

```
#PYTHON2 = $(shell pwd)/../../../venv3.7/bin/python
ESPIDF = $(shell pwd)/../../../esp-idf/
BOARD = GENERIC_SPIRAM
PORT = /dev/cu.SLAB_USBtoUART
FLASH_MODE = dio
FLASH_SIZE = 4MB
BAUD = 115200
```

In the makefile lazy setters are used ( ?=) for variables like the BOARD but still gmake ends up building GENERIC instead of GENERIC_SPIRAM.

Other settings like PORT are ignored as well and I cannot even erase any connected device as `/dev/cu.SLAB_USBtoUART` is always overwritten with '/dev/ttyUSB0'

I'm on OSX mojave.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

After countless hours of debugging I found out that even though OSX is case insenstive... It mattered that the `GNUMakefile` had a uppercase M while it should have been `GNUmakefile`

That was an expensive typo...